# Numpy EIG approximately 4x slower than MATLAB EIG on Mac OS X 10.6. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: macos, numpy, blas, accelerate-framework

I tried profiling the EIG function on MATLAB and NumPy to compare performance on my Macbook Pro (2 GHz, Quad core i7 running OS X 10.6). NumPy EIG appears to be quite slow compared to MATLAB.

Here's the code I profiled on NumPy:

```
s = '''\
x = numpy.random.random((2000,2000));
numpy.linalg.eig(x);
'''
t = timeit.Timer(stmt=s,setup="import numpy")
result = t.repeat(repeat=5,number=10)
result
Out[22]: 
[197.1737039089203,
 197.34872913360596,
 196.8160741329193,
 197.94081807136536,
 194.5740351676941]
```

That's around **19.5 secs/exec** in NumPy.

Here's the same code in MATLAB:

```
clear all
tic;
for i = 1:50
    x = rand(2000,2000);
    eig(x);
end
toc;
Elapsed time is 267.976645 seconds.
```

That's around **5.36 secs/exec** on MATLAB.

I guess something as simple as this should not depend much on JIT performance, so it probably boils down to BLAS and the routines that access the BLAS libraries. I know that MATLAB uses the Accelerate Framework on the Mac.

NumPy also appears to use the Accelerate Framework BLAS on my Macbook Pro; here's the output of `numpy.show_config()`

```
numpy.show_config()
lapack_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
blas_opt_info:
    extra_link_args = ['-Wl,-framework', '-Wl,Accelerate']
    extra_compile_args = ['-msse3', '-I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers']
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 3)]
```

I'm using Python 2.7.2 and NumPy 1.6 (both installed from MacPorts)

So here's my question to the NumPy folks:
Why is NumPy slower in this instance? Have I left out some optimization while installing NumPy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the MATLAB uses MKL libraries as BLAS, not the Accelerate Framework.
My experience tells me, that Accelerate is significantly slower than MKL. 
To check it, you can try to get the academic version of the Enthought Python Distribution (EPD), where Numpy is compiled against MKL, and compare these timings.
Moreover, by default, MATLAB uses all the threads (try running in single-threaded mode),
but Numpy is not.
In the EPD, it can be done with running

```
import mkl 
mkl.set_num_threads(4)
```

Comment: Also, r.e. no. of threads, I notice that both NumPy and MATLAB use all the four cores available on my machine when running EIG; however, the load when NumPy is running is a bit lower (not quantified yet) than when MATLAB is running.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading that right , you are profiling the performance of the random number generator in addition to the eig function. I made that mistake once years go comparing GAUSS to MATLAB -- I'd re-do factoring out the random number generation as see what you get.

one other note -- for some of the LAPACK/BLAS stuff, you can gt better performance if you make sure your numpy arrays are stored in Fortran order internally:

```
In [12]: x = numpy.random.random((200,200))

In [13]: x.flags
Out[13]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False


In [15]: x = numpy.array(x, order="F")

In [16]: x.flags
Out[16]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

-Chris

Comment: You're right about that -- but I separately tried to compare time taken for generating the random array on both NumPy and MATLAB, and they are roughly similar and negligible compared to EIG for an array this size -- you can profile the code to see where it's spending most of the time!

Comment: changing the array to Fortran order didn't help much for EIG. You can do `x = x.T` before calling EIG.

Answer (score 1):

The huge difference is because in MATLAB you are only calculating the eigenvalues but in python/numpy you are calculating both eigenvalues and eigenvectors. To correct this and make appropriate comparisons, you must do one of the following:
1. change numpy.linalg.eig(x) to numpy.linalg.eigvals(x) , leave matlab code as it is OR
2. change eig(x) to [V,D] = eig(x) in matlab, leave python/numpy code as it is (this might create more memory being consumed by matlab script)
in my experience, python/numpy optimized with MKL(I use windows; dont know much about acclerate framework) is as fast as or slightly faster than matlab optimized with MKL.